# Is this a valid macro in C?

Tags: c, macros

If  I use the macro:

```
#define AND
```

in the following way:

```
if(...)
{
...
}
elseANDif(...)
{
...
}
```

What output does the preprocessor produce?

**Edit:** 
I intend to use:

```
#define TEST(params) if(...){...}else
```

*the ... in if(...) is a complicated expression using params*

*the ... in {...} performs some operations & is independent of params*

```
#define AND

TEST(x1) AND TEST(x2)
{
    //the code for the final else
}
```

Is the AND helping here or can I do without it?

Comment: Your intended use is unreadable.  If anything, a reader would expect the `// the code for the final else` block to be executed if `a == b && b == c`, but that's entirely different from what your code actually would be doing.  Unless you're trying to devise an IOCCC entry, don't do it.

Comment: There are much better (as in more readable and less error-prone) ways of doing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this isn't going to work as you expect. And you can test what the preprocessor does by running your code through `cpp`.

```
eliben@eliben-desktop:~/temp$ cat z.c
#define AND

if(...)
{
    ...
}
elseANDif(...)
{
    ...
}

eliben@eliben-desktop:~/temp$ cpp z.c
# 1 "z.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "z.c"


if(...)
{
    ...
}
elseANDif(...)
{
    ...
}
```

The *technical* reason is that when `cpp` expands macros it looks for a complete identifier token matching this macro's name. I.e. in your case, it looks for the identifier `AND`. However when it parses the code it doesn't find such an identifier. It finds `elseANDif` which is quite a different identifier. It has no way to break `elseANDif` into constituents, and that's a good thing because otherwise macros would work very badly. Imagine:

```
const int FUSIONDEBUG = 5;
```

Whatever that means, in real C code this would break awfully, since `NDEBUG` is almost always defined in production code to be empty (google on what `NDEBUG` means).

---

Regarding your edit, the best advice I can give you on such matters is **DON'T DO IT**. (ab)Using macros like this may appear at first to make the code more readable, but in the long term it makes it much less readable, with the added peril that macros are tricky to get perfectly right and with certain combination of tokens can blow up on you badly.

So you can definitely do without the `AND` as well as without the `TEST` altogether.

Comment: i have a piece of code which checks whether a file has been successfully opened or not, based on which it either prints the error message or moves on to the actual file-io in the else part. Sometimes 2 files have to be opened, hence I have added an else to the previous macro. Any suggestions you can provide in getting this macro running would be  appreciated.

Comment: @crypto: I'll be glad to help but your need is still unclear to me from the comment. Since this is quite a different issue now, I suggest you open a separate SO question with an appropriate name and a detailed description of your requirements in the body of the question.

Comment: Eli's advice is right on. While it is seductive to use macros to tune the C language, that way is a path to madness. Just don't do it. On the other hand, it can on rare occasion make sense to use macros as a substitute for inline functions.

Comment: @crypto: There are always a gazillion ways to code any solution, so you may find another way. If you always want to print an error message, then you could put it into a wrapper function that contains the check, prints the message on error and return a success/failure indication. This would reduce your construct to something like `if (my_file_check(file1) && my_file_check(file2))`, reducing redundancy at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
#define TEST(condn) if(...){...}else
```

is nonsense; what do you expect the ellipses (...) to do!?

the example usage you gave would expand to

```
if(...){...} else if(...){...}else
{
    //the code for the final else
}
```

which is patently nonsense; where is the `condn` argument used?.  Either way whatever you really intended the AND has no effect other than dummy readability.  If you are trying to invent a new language, the C preprocessor is not the way to do this.  I can see no advantage to what you appear to be trying to achieve over more straightforward code.

If you intended:

```
 #define TEST(condn) if(condn){/*some code*/}else
```

then how is the resultant:

```
if(a==b){/*some code*/} else if(b==c){/*some code*/}else
{
    //the code for the final else
}
```

better than:

```
if(a==b || b==c)
{
    /*some code*/
} 
else
{
    //the code for the final else
}
```

where `/*some code*/` is not unnecessarily duplicated?

Note that here the single condition chained by `||` is equivalent to your multiple conditions chained by `else if`, so even if you use the `TEST` macro, there is no need to use it that way when:

```
TEST( a==b || b==c)
{
    //the code for the final else
}
```

will suffice.

Macros are often ill-advised at the best of times, but you have chosen a particularly prime example of macro abuse!  Consider for example how you might debug such code in a source-level debugger.

Comment: I agree with your point, but do you honestly believe I have ellipsis(...) in my if code?

Comment: Please read the edit now, I have modified it to properly portray what I am doing.

Comment: @crypto: Of course not, but why post it that way!? It just creates ambiguity unnecessarily.  It may also have been an incorrect attempt at a variadic macro.  The edit does not help clarify much.  If you can't show what you are doing, there is little point is posting it at all.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is "yes". You can certainly do what you are suggesting. Here is a basic, working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define AND
#define TEST(params) if (!params) { printf(#params " was false\n"); } else 

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int param_1 = 1;
    int param_2 = 0;

    TEST(param_1) AND TEST(param_2)
    {
        printf("success!\n");
    }
}
```

After macro expansion, the code would essentially look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int param_1 = 1;
    int param_2 = 0;

    if (!param_1) { printf("param_1 was false\n"); } else 
    if (!param_2) { printf("param_2 was false\n"); } else
    {
        printf("success!\n");
    }
}
```

As pointed out by others, doing something like this is questionable because it messes with the way people read code and can make future debugging difficult. In a case such as this, I would definitely recommend using a function call if at all possible. This is the approach that Secure recommends in his comment:

```
int test_parameters(int params)
{
    if (!params) { printf("bad parameters"); return 0; }
    else { return 1; }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    int param_1 = 1;
    int param_2 = 0;

    if (test_parameters(param_1) && test_parameters(param_2))
    {
        printf("success!\n");
    }
}
```